# Returning a pointer and passing in a const reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, httprequest, poco-libraries

While trying to learn about poco networking libraries [here](http://xjia.heroku.com/2011/09/11/learning-poco-a-simple-http-server/), I came across the following snippet:

```
class MyRequestHandlerFactory : public HTTPRequestHandlerFactory
{
public:
  virtual HTTPRequestHandler* createRequestHandler(const HTTPServerRequest &)
  {
    return new MyRequestHandler;
  }
};
```

I am having trouble understanding the return type of the method (`HTTPRequestHandler*`) and the arguments to the method(`const HTTPServerRequest &`).

Why is it that the return type a `HTTPRequestHandler` pointer? Does `new MyRequestHandler` return an address to an object which can be referred to by its base type?

Also, I understand `const` is used to make the reference immutable so that the method does not mutate the referenced object but there's no name provided for the reference type and its not being used in the `createRequestHandler` method. Can somebody tell me what might be going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Return type**

If you look at the "Learning Poco" code web site,

```
class MyRequestHandler : public HTTPRequestHandler
{
    // ... removed code
};
```

MyRequestHandler is derived from HTTPRequestHandler. So, MyRequestHandler is a HTTPRequestHandler because of inheritance. So it is valid to return a pointer to a MyRequestHandler, because it is also a pointer to a HTTPRequestHandler.

**Function Argument**

The snippet is confusing because it specifies an argument as a type but no variable name. It is in fact the same as:

```
class MyRequestHandlerFactory : public HTTPRequestHandlerFactory
{
public:
  virtual HTTPRequestHandler* createRequestHandler(const HTTPServerRequest & notUsed)
  {
    return new MyRequestHandler;
  }
};
```

The 'notUsed' variable is ... not used. So you ask, why is there an argument at all? Because it is overriding a function declared in the base class HTTPRequestHandlerFactory. This function will have an argument `const HTTPServerRequest &`, therefore it must also appear in the overriding function in the derived class (even though it is not used). If 'notUsed' were to be used in the function `createRequestHandler()`, the `const` keyword ensures that it cannot be changed inside `createRequestHandler()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to return a way to access an object without making a copy of it in C++: return a pointer to it or return a reference to it. Pointers tend to be the preferred method for a variety of reasons (references are not reassignable, for example).
Note that if it returned `HTTPRequestHandler` and not a pointer to it then that would mean the object would be copied.

The argument name doesn't have to be provided because it's not used. The type has to be provided so the function signature is complete. You similarly do not have to provide names when forward declaring a function since the compiler only cares about the types and the order they come in.